# fail to receive multiple values returned from stored procedure by using dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oop, stored-procedures

I would like to return multiple values from stored procedure (attached as below) by having userid as parameter. I tried to receive the multiple values by using function with dataset (attached as below) but failed and I got the error lists like this:

Error 2 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to 'string'

Error 5 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.SqlDataAdapter(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments

Error 6 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' to 'string'

Appreciate for any reply. Million thanks.

SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE abc.testing

@userid int

AS

SELECT * FROM ss2_table
WHERE userid=@userid
```

C#:

```
public DataSet get_testing(int userid)
{
    DataSet ds_testing_total = null;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Userid=abc;Password=abc;Server=admin;Database=ss2"))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmdselect1 = new SqlCommand();
            cmdselect1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdselect1.CommandText = "abc.testing";
            cmdselect1.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = userid;
            cmdselect1.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();


            SqlDataAdapter dap1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdselect1, connection);
            ds_testing_total = new DataSet();
            dap1.Fill(ds_testing_total, "ss2_table");

            return ds_testing_total;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: How do you know it fails?  Do you get no data?  Are you seeing an exception?  Have you run the proc in SQL Server Management Studio to see if it works?

Comment: new SqlDataAdapter(cmdselect1, connection);
this line is red-lined and the proc should work well.

Comment: The IDE should give you information on why the red line is appearing if you mouse over it.  Does it?

Comment: @Tim, ya, I edited and posted it.

Comment: @SƲmmērAƥ Check out the existing solutions, if they work, please uprank and select and best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Should be:**

```
SqlDataAdapter dap1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdselect1.CommandText, connection);
```

-or-

```
SqlDataAdapter dap1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdselect1);
```

**Not:**

```
SqlDataAdapter dap1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdselect1, connection);
```

Also, you can create a new SqlCommand by using connection.CreateCommand() rather than new SqlCommand() and setting the connection.

```
SqlCommand cmdselect1 = connection.CreateCommand();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find an overload of the `SqlDataAdapter`'s constructor that takes a `SqlCommand` *and* a `SqlConnection`. That would probably explain why it has been red lined.

The `SqlCommand` contains a reference to the `SqlConnection` so you should just be able to:

```
SqlDataAdapter dap1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdselect1);
```